# PowerEdge 1950 server won't boot up - rcu_sched kthread starved

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

Two weeks ago we had a power outage after that my home server (running Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS) didn't boot, I spent a day trying to boot in recovery mode, running memtest, booting Ubuntu Desktop (also had the same problem first) and running fsck, finally it started without issues. (Memtest and fsck didn't find anything).
Today I had to restart the server and the same happened and I tought better to ask here than waste a whole day trying to fix it just to find out that it wasn't a fix.
In the span of the two weeks while the server was running i didn't notice anything misbehaving so i think it isn't a hardware problem.
After I did some research I found the [documentation of the RCU's CPU Stall Detector](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/stallwarn.txt) after reading through I got a better understanding what's going on, but still I have no idea on how to fix it, also I found sites which tells to set different things in the boot command, but since it worked before with the same command and I don't know which option does what I didn't changed that.
For me the call trace doesn't tell much, but for someone it might be useful.
[image]

Comment: what kernel version you are trying to boot? have you tried to disable HyperThreading in BIOS?

Comment: I tried 5.4.0-65 and -62. HyperThreading isn't supported by my processor.

Comment: Try to turn off ACPI in kernel boot arguments, change this in grub (acpi=off)

Comment: It works, thank you. If you could explain what does this change and why it works I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: my advice for you, update BIOS and iDRAC firmware, update Intel CPU microcode (follow https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-update-intel-microcode-firmware-linux/) and then boot. Without ACPI, you won't turn off your server by pressing power button, more about ACPI ref Wikipedia or Google.